# How to verify that a specific lambda method has been passed as argument with mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlintest

I have a Kotlin class (The problem was simplified to have a basic example), in it there is a method `testedMethod()` I want to test interactions on.

I want to make sure the correct parameter is passed to `anotherMethod()`, my problem is that the parameter is not a *value* but a *lambda function*.

A simple solution in Kotlin is what I am looking for, it may or may not be based on [this solution for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462913/mockito-verify-that-a-specific-lambda-has-been-passed-as-an-argument-in-mocks-m).

```
class TestedClass {

    fun testedMethod() {
        anotherMethod({ passedMethod() })
    }

    fun passedMethod() {}

    fun anotherMethod(lambdaParameter: () -> Unit) {
        // Does something with lambdaParameter
    }
}
```

Comment: If lambda is used/called within  `anotherMethod` then mock `passedMethod`. After which you exercise `testedMethod` and then verify that the mocked `passedMethod` was invoked.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I ended up using.

Basically you create a `spy` of the tested class to be able to verify its own method, and you use `argumentCaptor` to capture the passed lambda and be able to invoke what is in it.

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.argumentCaptor
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.spy
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify

@Test
fun lambdaParameterPassedIsCorrect() {
    val testedClass = TestedClass()
    val spyOfTestedClass = spy(testedClass)

    val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>()

    spyOfTestedClass.testedMethod()

    verify(spyOfTestedClass).anotherMethod(captor.capture())
    // Invoke the function passed as a parameter 
    // and then verify that the expected method was called
    val function = captor.firstValue
    function.invoke()
    verify(spyOfTestedClass).passedMethod()
}
```

I would still be interested in a simpler solution.

Comment: I try to implement my case based on your answer but failed, for example val captor = argumentCaptor<() -> Unit>() -- give me an error

Answer (score -1):

You can use mockito_kotlin library, which have the function "verify".

```
  verify(TestedClass, times(1)).anotherMethod(eq(passedMethod))
```

Which verify that the method "anotherMethod" of class "TestedClass" invoked once with the parameter equal to "passedMethod"

Comment: Could you please provide a code example with the complete syntax that compiles and where the test passes?
I thought it would be that easy before posting this question ;)