# Getting Null Pointer Exception in a Mockito method call which requires predicate as a parameter

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
@Mock
RefDataCache refDataCache;

TradingAccountEntity tradingAccountEntity = Mockito.mock(TradingAccountEntity.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
tradingAccountEntity.setMethod1(65);
tradingAccountEntity.setMethod2(65);
Mockito.when(refDataCache.getTradingAccount(x-> x.getMethod1()==65)).thenReturn(tradingAccountEntity);
Mockito.when(tradingAccountEntity.getMethod2()).thenReturn((long) 65);
```

In the above code, I am getting `NullPointerException` stating :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "getMethod1()" because the return value of "getTradingAccount(org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate)" is null.
```

I tried changing the code to :

```
Mockito.when(refDataCache.getTradingAccount(65)).thenReturn(tradingAccountEntity);
Mockito.when(tradingAccountEntity.getMethod2()).thenReturn((long) 65);
```

Then it shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "getMethod2()" because the return value of "getTradingAccount(org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate)" is null.
```

I am not able to understand How should I pass value to `getTradingAccount()` so that it does not give `NullPointerException`.
Please help.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: 13:11:00.746 [main] ERROR PostingService - Error occurred while placing Quote for QuoteRequest: 65
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "refdatacache.TradingAccountEntity.getMethod2()" because the return value of "refdatacache.RefDataCache.getTradingAccount(org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate)" is null

Comment: `Mockito.when(refDataCache.getTradingAccount(x-> x.getMethod1()==65))` should probably be `Mockito.when(refDataCache.getTradingAccount(any(Predicate.class)))`, you can't really mock lambdas *exactly* because they don't overwrite `equals()` or `hashCode()`, so unless you pass the *exact* same lambda everywhere, your mock method will not match. Futher reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462913/mockito-verify-that-a-specific-lambda-has-been-passed-as-an-argument-in-mocks-m

Comment: @Lino Let me try the change you suggested.